# How to find item in object by value in JS

Tags: javascript, object

There are many questions about this, but none of them solved my problem.

I have this object:

```
const default_keys = {
    l: 1, 
    t: 5,
    o: 10, 
    r: 50, 
    w: 100,
    y: 500,
    m: 1000,
    f: 5000,
    a: 10000,
    z: 50000,
    d: 100000,
    q: 1000000
};
```

so, among all these key:value items, I want to know which key has the value = 100
(in this case it should return "w");

is it possible?

EDIT: I tried this solution, but it didn't work because it only works with fixed key names:

```
const object1 = {
  a: {val: "aa"},
  b: {val: "bb"},
  c: {val: "cc"}
};

let a = Object.values(object1).find((obj) => {
    return obj.val == "bb"
});
```

in this case the fixed name is "val", but in my case there is no fixed name..

Comment: `but none of them solved my problem.` ← Include what you have tried and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object with switched key/value pairs and get the key by taking the value as key.

```js
const 
    keys = { l: 1,  t: 5, o: 10,  r: 50,  w: 100, y: 500, m: 1000, f: 5000, a: 10000, z: 50000, d: 100000, q: 1000000 },
    values = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(keys).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]));

console.log(values[100]);
```

Comment: I was just scratching my chin, wondering if the OP accounted for the possibility of non-unique values. Wondering if any of the answers would.  When I saw your handle here I knew that yours would.  Imagine my surprise.

Comment: @danh - How does this account for non-unique values? Creating a new object with key-value pairs reversed would destroy any duplicates since an object can't have duplicate keys. It's a clever idea, as usual, but hard to read and overkill IMO.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., assuming op wants to check more than one value, then this approach is faster than to iterate all pairs until the found value.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce, I was being obtuse, complaining that this solution (like all the others) fails to account for non-unique values. Yours is most easily fixed (replacing find with filter). This one, as the author points out trades a little space and a linear pre-processing time for O(1) lookups... great as long as there are unique values

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Yes this one would be faster if you're making more than one lookup using the same map.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to iterate thru [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const default_keys = {
    l: 1, 
    t: 5,
    o: 10, 
    r: 50, 
    w: 100,
    y: 500,
    m: 1000,
    f: 5000,
    a: 10000,
    z: 50000,
    d: 100000,
    q: 1000000
};

function getKey(object, value){
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if(v == value) return k;
  }
}

console.log(getKey(default_keys, 100));
```

Another way would be to use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const default_keys = {
  l: 1,
  t: 5,
  o: 10,
  r: 50,
  w: 100,
  y: 500,
  m: 1000,
  f: 5000,
  a: 10000,
  z: 50000,
  d: 100000,
  q: 1000000
};

function getKey(object, value) {
  let entry = Object.entries(object).find(item => item[1] == value);
  if (entry) return entry[0];
}

console.log(getKey(default_keys, 100));
```

Comment: I like this the most, except I think it should filter object entries and return an array of matching keys

Answer (score 2):

Using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
const getKeyWithValue = (obj = {}, value) => {
  let key;
  for(const prop in default_keys) {
    if(default_keys[prop] === value) {
      key = prop;
      break;
    }
  }
  return key;
}

const default_keys = { l: 1, t: 5, o: 10,  r: 50,  w: 100, y: 500, m: 1000, f: 5000, a: 10000, z: 50000, d: 100000, q: 1000000 };
console.log( getKeyWithValue(default_keys, 100) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways to do it:

### Using for-in

```
const default_keys = {
  l: 1,
  t: 5,
  o: 10,
  r: 50,
  w: 100,
  y: 500,
  m: 1000,
  f: 5000,
  a: 10000,
  z: 50000,
  d: 100000,
  q: 1000000
}

// Method 1 using 'for in'
for (const key in default_keys) {
  if (default_keys[key] === 100) {
    console.log('For in: ', key)
  }
}
```

### Using Object.keys and loops

```
// Method 2 using Object.keys and loops

let keys = Object.keys(default_keys)
keys.forEach(key => {
  if (default_keys[key] === 100) console.log('Using Object.keys and loops: ', key)
})
```

### Using Object.entries

```
// Method 3: Functional Approach and using Object.entries
function getKey(obj) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (value === 100) {
      return key
    }
  }
}
console.log('Functional Approach:', getKey(default_keys))
```

Comment: Looks like you copied and slightly modified my answer.

Comment: Lol no, it is just a coincidence.  There are a finite number of ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Nice edit. +1 for a unique idea,

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way is to use the `filter()` function.

```js
const default_keys = {
    l: 1, 
    t: 5,
    o: 10, 
    r: 50, 
    w: 100,
    y: 500,
    m: 1000,
    f: 5000,
    a: 10000,
    z: 50000,
    d: 100000,
    q: 1000000
};
console.log(Object.keys(default_keys).filter((item) => default_keys[item] == 100)[0]);
```

In case you want to receive multiple results, you can remove `[0]` and you will get an array then.